# SPRESENSE（Arduino版）で録音とデータ送信を同時に行いたい

Tags: spresense, http, arduino, audio

SPRESENSEのArduino版で現在、録音を行うセンサを作ろうと考えております。
SONY developer world 記載のチュートリアルを参考にして、SD内に録音データを保存してそのデータをサーバにアップロードするような実装はできたのですが、この際、録音後のアップロードとなってしまいます。

録音とデータのアップロードを行うことは可能でしょうか。
有識者の方がいらっしゃいましたらご教示いただけますと幸いです。

参考ページ： (Spresense Arduino チュートリアル)

- [MP3 形式で録音する](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/arduino_tutorials_ja.html#_mp3_recorder)
- [HTTP GETメソッドをサーバに送信してデータを取得する](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/arduino_tutorials_ja.html#_http_get%E3%83%A1%E3%82%BD%E3%83%83%E3%83%89%E3%82%92%E3%82%B5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%90%E3%81%AB%E9%80%81%E4%BF%A1%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%83%87%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%82%92%E5%8F%96%E5%BE%97%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

こちら、録音とアップロードを同時に行いたいという質問ですよね？それを前提とした答えとしますが、、、

録音とアップロードが同時にできるかは録音するメディアの書き込み速度とアップロードの速度によります。どれくらいの速度で処理すべきかは計算ですぐに出てきます。例えばサンプリングレートが48000Hz でデータ量を1024サンプルとします。このデータを取得するまでの時間は 1024/48000 になるので 21.333ミリ秒になります。

つまり21.3333ミリ秒の間に録音とデータ送信ができないと、FIFOに処理しきれないデータが蓄積してしまい、どこかのタイミングでFIFOがオーバーフローしてしまい処理が止まります。

ですので、処理したいデータ量のメディア書き込み時間とアップロード時間を計測してみてれば、おおよそ可能かどうかわかります。

あと、やったことはないので、あくまで可能性の話ですが、、、

SPRESENSEはサブコアが使えますので、サブコアに送信するデータのコピーを渡せば、メインコアでメディアへの書き込み、サブコアでデータ送信と並行処理ができるかも知れません。もし出来れば処理の時間短縮が見込めます。

Comment: ご回答いただき、ありがとうございます!! Ardinoは基本的にsetupからmain loopにつながると思うのですが、この際どのようにして並列処理を実行すればよいでしょうか。参考になるページ等ありましたらお教えいただけませんでしょうか

Comment: 手前みそですが、次のサイトにサンプルがあります。
「SPRESENSEのマルチコアでLEDを制御してみた」
https://makers-with-myson.blog.ss-blog.jp/2019-10-27
「SPRESENSE でスレッドを走らせてみた！」
https://makers-with-myson.blog.ss-blog.jp/2019-10-19
「SPRESENSE で pthread でLEDを制御してみた！」
https://makers-with-myson.blog.ss-blog.jp/2019-11-04

マルチコアプログラミングに関しては次の書籍も参考になると思います。
「SPRESENSEではじめるローパワーエッジAI」
https://www.oreilly.co.jp/books/9784873119670/

Comment: ありがとうございます！大変参考になりました。
どうやら、SPRESENSEのArduino互換版はNuttxで動いているようで、Nuttxの子pthreadが使えました。
ご回答いただき、ありがとうございました。